# php openssl library not loaded error in terminal

Tags: php, terminal, openssl

I run php7.2 on mac os mojave. I recently noticed when I run `php -v` in terminal I get this error

[image]

I am not sure what caused it because I noticed it today. uninstalling openssl using homebrew & installing again didn't work.

Comment: please share ubuntu version

Answer (score 0):

I installed new php version, php7.72 , it fixed the issue for me.